# What is the spanning set for $M=\{A \in M^{\mathbb C}_{n \times n}|A=-\overline A\}$ over $\mathbb R$?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

> I need to find the spanning set for $M=\{A \in M^{\mathbb C}_{n \times n}|A=-\overline A\}$ over $\mathbb R$.

This question is in continuation to this: [Is $M=\{A \in M^{\mathbb C}_{n \times n}|A=-\overline A\}$ a vector subspace over $\mathbb C$ and over $\mathbb R$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2277921/is-m-a-in-m-mathbb-c-n-times-na-overline-a-a-vector-subspace-ove) from which we learned that every element of $M$ must be an imaginary number.

So for example for matrix $M_{2 \times 2}$:
$$
Sp(M)=\{\begin{pmatrix}i&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix}0&i\\0&0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix}0&0\\i&0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix}0&0\\0&i \end{pmatrix}    \}
$$

By this logic a matrix $M_{n \times n}$ would have $n^2$ matrices in the spanning set.

How would I go about the general $Sp(M)$ for matrix is size $n \times n$? Can I write as follows:
$$
\text{for }1 \le i \le n^2\\
1\le j \le n\\
M_i \text{ such that } a_{ij}=i, \text{ while all other elements are equal to }0
$$
?

Comment: @user251257 I don't understand the connection

Comment: ah, my bad. I misunderstood the question. You are right. However I would recommend to write $M_{k,l}$ where the $(k,l)$ component is $i$ and otherwise $0$.